# send tdata frame to a socket

Tags: java, android, byte, frame

byte[] demande=new byte[2];
Let's suppose that demande is a data frame which will be send to a socket.
What should be byte[0] and byte[1] if I want send 200. I try to write byte[0]=1 and byte[1]=-56 ( 1*256 - 56)=200 but it don't work. How can I do?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the number 200 is a decimal value.
As 200 is less than 255 it will fit into one byte because the hexadecimal value of 200 is 0xC8.

So in your case you have two options. Which one is correct depends on the protocol you are using.

Either

```
byte[] demande = { 0x00, 0xC8 };  // little endian
```

or

```
byte[] demande = { 0xC8, 0x00 };  // big endian
```

Or if you prefer

```
byte[] demande = new byte[2];
demande[0] = 0x00;
demande[1] = 0xC8;
```

(little endian)

Comment: 0xC8 is not accepted , max 0x80 is accepted cause I think its a signed byte -128 to 128

Comment: @pape Without reading the protocol for the device you are communicating with it is difficult to give better advice. You could try to send three bytes like byte[] demande = { '2', '0', '0' }; if it is an ASCII protocol.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [ByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/class-use/ByteBuffer.html) class to create a byte array. If you wanted to convert the integer 200 to a byte array:

```
ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(2);
b.putInt(0x000000c8);

byte[] result = b.array();
```